# What is meant by bore and stroke?

Tags: engine, engine-theory, four-stroke

All engine specifications reflect a bore and stroke number.

**Example**

Aprilia Tuono V4 R

2012

Four stroke, longitudinal 65° V four , DOHC, 4 valves per cylinder

998.9 cc / 60.96 cu in

Bore x Stroke
78 x 52.3 mm
Compression Ratio
13.0:1

There are characteristics of an engine that are reflected in the bore x stroke values.

**Questions**

What exactly is bore x stroke?

How do bore x stroke values effect efficiency in an engine?

Why is it so important for engine manufacturers to reflect bore x stroke numbers in their promotion of a vehicle?

Is there something about bore x stroke values that are important to consumers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Bore** is the diameter of each cylinder and **stroke** is the length that it travels when moving from bottom position to the top position. Thus if the engine has 1 cylinder with bore x stroke of 78 x 52.3 mm it's total displacement will be: 
[image: Displacement formula] 
where π = 3.1416... and the bore and stroke must be in cm, thus divide them by 10 to get the right dimension. For your example it will be:
[image: Displacement example]

Engines with the bore bigger than stroke (like your example) are called **oversquare** engines, with the bore smaller than stroke are called **undersquare** engines and exactly equal are called **square** engines.
**Oversquare** engines allow bigger or multiple valves in the head and have less loss to friction due to the shorter stroke, but are only efficient at higher revs thus are more typical in high performance engines, like in your example for a sport bike. Bigger engines also have a larger bore even in trucks to limit the length of the stroke, thus limiting losses of the pistons rubbing the rings.
**Undersquare** engines allow for a better torque in low revolutions where the longer stroke will not affect performance so much but the fuel burn will be more efficient due to the lower volume when the air/fuel mixture is compressed, leading also to lower fuel consumption. Diesel engines also are massively undersquare engines (typically around 3:1 ratio) since those engines have a very high compression ratio compared to gas engines (around 22:1 ratio).
A long time ago the tax on cars in England was applied proportional to the bore size, thus even high performance cars like Jaguars had unusual long strokes to allow a high displacement while still paying lower taxes.

IMHO many other factors will dictate the performance and fuel consumption of the engine, thus only looking at the bore x stroke ratio is meaningless, yet by rule of thumb you can say that big bore gives you higher performance at high revs and long stroke gives you lower fuel consumption at everyday usage.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to user your answer for a tag-wiki.  Which was my intent.  Nice and TY

Comment: @DucatiKiller Thanks you liked and it was useful for you!

Comment: @DucatiKiller If you need more detailed information about the subject at Wikipedia there is a excellent article about this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroke_ratio

Answer (score -5):

Stroke is length of stroke and bore is diameter.  Yes it matters in linear speed of cylinder.  Big block engines will go with really big bore as you get to a limit on stroke.

So important?  It is just a facts about the engine.

Comment: Lacks description.  Tell me like I'm 5.

Comment: You are driving at 5?  What part of diameter confuses you?

Comment: Just letting you know why I down voted.  You can behave that way when I'm doing you a favor and trying to help you in the site.  You should thank

Comment: I am answering your question and you are doing me a favor?  Again - what part of diameter confuses you?  Or is that not taught until the second grade?

Comment: You didn't answer anything. Read the questions.  I'm not hating on you. I'm giving you guidance.  Your answer is rudimentary at best.

Comment: Didn't answer anything.  Let's start with bore is diameter.  For the third time what part of diameter is not clear?    I will give you guidance - that is multiple questions.  Efficiency and promotion are separate questions.  Important to consumer is dependent on the consumer.

Comment: Yup. Your very smart.  Your insults are reflect any of insecurity driven by fear.  Your rude and immature.  Your comments reflect spitefullnes and a general lack

Comment: Take care.   Cheers.

Comment: For the fourth time what part of diameter is not clear? Your and you're are different words.

Comment: Sheez, and here I thought trolls only existed on usenet.

Comment: What do mean @BillOer  this guy probably is from Usenet.  You can tell because he repeats himself, behaves like a child and yells at his mom to get him more hot pockets.